# Run nmcli commands in chroot environnement

Tags: networking, networkmanager, chroot, nmcli

I have set up a chroot environment (Ubuntu Jammy). I need to run the `nmcli` command for some purposes. `nmcli` depend on `NetworkManager.service`, but the systemd service isn't allowed in chroot env.

How to make `nmcli` commands available in chroot?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NetworkManager can be executed with `--no-daemon` option in background, making the `nmcli` to work independently of the systemd service :

```
/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon &
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to somehow allow communication with the "host" NetworkManager daemon, so, a dbus-enabling bind mount?

I'm not sure nmcli works without access to the config files in /etc, so that's another bind mount you might need.

I'm either case, running `strace -o /tmp/nmcli strace nmcli` should tell you what it needs; it's how I figure out what I need to expose to containers.